# How to write an data array to excel in a row instead of in a column using pandas in Python

Tags: python, arrays, excel, pandas

```
a= [1,2,3,4,5]
df=DataFrame(a)
```

.... #setup excelwriter and dataframe

```
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheetname,startrow=1, startcol=1, header=False, index=False)
```

Output:

```
1\n
2\n
3\n
4\n
5
```

How can I get output as:

```
1    2    3    4    5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To output in a line use this:

```
df = df.transpose()
```

Full code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import pandas as pd 
import xlsxwriter as xlsw

a = [1,2,3,4,5]
df = pd.DataFrame(a)
df = df.transpose()
xlsfile = 'pandas_simple.xlsx'
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(xlsfile, engine='xlsxwriter')

df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Sheet1Name",startrow=1, startcol=1, header=False, index=False)
```

https://github.com/tigertv/stackoverflow-answers

Answer (score 2):

You could transpose first, and then save to excel:

```
df

   0
0  1
1  2
2  3
3  4
4  5

df.T.to_excel(writer, 
              sheet_name=sheetname,
              startrow=1, 
              startcol=1, 
              header=False, 
              index=False)
```

```
1   2   3   4   5
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `transpose`() on dataframe to convert columns into rows.

```
import pandas as pd

a= [1,2,3,4,5]
df=pd.DataFrame(a)
df = df.transpose()

print(df)
```

result:

```
   0  1  2  3  4
0  1  2  3  4  5
```

Comment: T and `transpose` are exactly the same. Mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48613193/4909087

Comment: Use transfpose() - typo

Comment: There was a point to my comment. Please look at the other answers before posting your own. Cheers.