# How to write Pandas Dataframe Horizontally in to Excel sheet from python openpyxl (elements in same row, consecutive columns)

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, openpyxl

I have this problem where I am able to write Pandas dataframe into excel using openpyxl and it works fine where the dataframe is written vertically.( Same column, consecutive rows)

but I want to write my dataframe horizontally i.e. elements in same row, consecutive columns

My dataframe is a single dimensional one like [10, 9,8,7,6]

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(fn, engine='openpyxl')

writer.book = book
writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)

#df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', header=None, index=False)
df_2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet3', header=None, index=False,
             startcol=1,startrow=1)

writer.save()
```

My question is:

Can we define into this code snippet whether the data frame should be written vertically or horizontally just like startrow and startcol.

I've searched everywhere but could not find any.

Comment: First use df2 = df2.transpose()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should solve your problem:

```
df2 = df2.transpose()
df_2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet3', header=None, index=False,
         startcol=1,startrow=1)
```

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48613390/8719679)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried transposing the dataframe before writing it ? 
e.g.

`df_2.T.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet3', header=None, index=False, startcol=1,startrow=1)`

Comment: I have used the same but do not get my desired result.